# Problem integrating ros with opencv to work with rgb camera output in ros

Tags: ros, c++, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to integrate the normal rgb camera output (OpenCV) with ros using cv_bridge and image_transport. When I compile(catkin_make) the code I receive the following error -

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_calib3d/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcv_bridge.so.
```

Any help would be appreciated. The project is for my university assignment and is slightly urgent. Below is also the cmakelists.txt file that I am using .

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(image_pro)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  actionlib_msgs
  cv_bridge
  geometry_msgs
  image_transport
  move_base_msgs
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  pluginlib
  cmake_modules
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem date_time thread)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES image_pro
  CATKIN_DEPENDS actionlib_msgs cv_bridge geometry_msgs image_transport move_base_msgs nav_msgs roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs
  DEPENDS opencv eigen
)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#include_directories(include)
## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/image_pro.cpp
# )

add_executable(get_image_node src/get_image.cpp)
#add_executable(image_pro src/obj_detect.cpp)
target_link_libraries(get_image_node ${OpenCV_LIBS}${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267685/problem-integrating-ros-with-opencv-to-work-with-rgb-camera-output-in-ros./) by [the_notorious_kid](https://answers.ros.org/users/31383/the_notorious_kid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're missing a space:

```
${OpenCV_LIBS}${catkin_LIBRARIES}
```

->

```
${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [the_notorious_kid](https://answers.ros.org/users/31383/the_notorious_kid/) on 2017-07-31**:
Thanks Lucas it worked. It was a rookie mistake.